# Where does Photo Booth store photos and videos?

Tags: macos, photo-booth

I want to automatically backup photos and videos from Photo Booth to Google Photos, but don't know where they are stored.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The PhotoBooth Library is within the Pictures folder of your Home Folder.

Regarding automatic backup, there is no direct way to do it as Photo Booth does not have many options for that. You can try following:

Get [Desktop Uploader app](https://photos.google.com/apps) for Google Photos. Alternative way to get it is by opening the sidebar on Google Photos in your browser and clicking App downloads.

After installing the app and logging into your Google account, you can select which folders Google Photos will automatically back up. So try to 
add this path to auto backup:

`"/Users/your_username/Pictures/Photo Booth Library/Pictures"`

You can right-click "Photo Booth Library", and select "Show Package Contents" to see the Pictures folder, or open directly from Terminal with: `open ~/Pictures/Photo\ Booth\ Library/Pictures`

Comment: Sure enough the movies are also stored in the mentioned `Pictures` directory.  Go figure...

Answer (score 3):

**Photo Booth.app** stores its original photos at:

> `~/Pictures/Photo Booth Library/Pictures/`

File names are in the form of `Photo on 10-11-12 at 10.11 AM.jpg`

From Finder, Right Click > Show Package Contents on the Photo Booth Library file to explore its contents.

Answer (score 2):

they are stored in Photo-Booth Application

you can create/use following command to create a symbolic link, to link photo-booth-pics directory under your Pictures directory

```
ln -s ~/Pictures/Photo\ Booth\ Library/Pictures ~/Pictures/photo-booth-pics
```

After above command Go to **/Users/*your_user_name*/Pictures/photo-booth-pics/**
to see your pics